# My Default dialer application rejected many time because I m using read call log permission

Tags: android, google-developers-console

I m uploading an application to the play store with a Default phone handler along with Read call log permission.
I m also Submitted a Google permission declaration form along with selected only the default phone handler but every time google rejected my app.
My application has a Default calling screen UI, Default Dialer, and also Identify Unknown Number with his name. My app has totally looked like a Truecaller app.
But My app getting rejected every time while I upload on the play store
Rejected Reason:-
Unable to verify core functionality of the app
When you submitted your app, you specified your app's core functionality as follows: Default Phone handler (and any other core functionality usage while default handler). However, we couldn’t find evidence that the app offers the declared core functionality during our review. Please submit an updated Permissions Declaration Form that includes instructions on how to verify your declared functionality, and include details such as test account information. If portions of your app are restricted, please share a link to a video of your app to help us verify the core functionalities you’ve declared.
Sir, Please help me to upload my app